# Removing columns with all row entries of all zero except for the first occurrence

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

I have a big matrix with 3 rows and many columns. I want to remove the columns which have zeroes in all its rows except for the first occurrence.

For example, given the following matrix:

```
    1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
A = 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
    1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

It would thus be transformed to:

```
    1 1 0 0 0 
A = 1 0 0 1 0 
    1 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Your example still has a zero column, is this intentional?

Comment: yes, i want to keep the first column from where zeros are starting

Comment: Will there always be or do you always want a column of all zeros?

Comment: There is an important edge case you have to consider.  What happens if you have a column of zeroes in between relevant data?  For example, let's say your matrix `A` had a column of zeroes in between the second and third column and these both have at least one row that is non-zero.  What would be the desired output?  Would you keep this column of zeroes while throwing out the other zero columns?

Comment: it's not necessary that the zeros will come. but if they come, i want to keep the first column of it! The algorithm is such that zeros will not come in between two non-zero columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) and search along all rows for every column to see if every element in a column is equal to 0.  We use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to determine these column locations.  As soon as you do that, make a copy of the original matrix, then dump all columns that have zeroes except for the first time we encounter such a column:

```
ind = find(all(A == 0, 1));
out = A;
out(:,ind(2:end)) = [];
```

With your example, we get:

```
>> out
out =
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     1     0
     1     0     1     1     0
```

A nice point about this approach is that even if there are no columns of complete zero, `find` will return an empty array and slicing into an empty array will also produce an empty array.  The removal step at the last line of code will thus have no effect and you maintain the same matrix as you did before.

---

If the constraint is maintained such that you will only see columns of zeroes at the end of your matrix and they don't appear in between valid data, we can do this by combining `any` and `all` with logical indexing:

```
out = A(:,any(A,1) | diff([false all(A == 0, 1)]));
```

We build a mask where the first part of it consists of all of the columns that are non-zero.  [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) in this context will find all columns that are non-zero.  This should happen at the very beginning of your data thus building the first half of the mask.  The next part uses [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to find pairwise differences in combination with the array that is output by the same `all` call that we have seen before.  We are assuming that the first column will never be non-zero (which is your case), and so padding an array where the first element is `false` followed by the same `all` call will determine a logical array where there will be only **one** time that the difference returned is non-zero, which is the point where the first zero column is returned.  We set this location in the mask to be true as well as all other locations that are non-zero, and we finally subset into your matrix thus achieving your result.

Answer (score 2):

```
 b = any(A);
 b(find(b == 0,1)) = 1;
 A=A(:,b)
```

fixed per comments to match op

Comment: this will also remove the first column from where zeros are starting. I want to keep  that column as I explained by example!

Comment: This removes all columns of complete zero.  The OP also wants to retain the first occurrence of a column of all zero.